# Para que serve e como usar os valores fit-content, max-content, e min-content da propriedade width?

Tags: css

Eu já lê várias documentações sobre esses valores da propriedade `width`, mas não consegui entender para que serve. Pelo que eu testei nos meus exemplos o resultado é aparentemente o mesmo. Por exemplo, quando é usado o valor `fit-content` na propriedade `width` no elemento especificado, ele tem a aparência de um elemento `inline`.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

        div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        p {
            width: fit-content;
            background: green;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>width</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Quando é usado o valor `max-content` ele tem o mesmo efeito.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

        div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        p {
            width: max-content;
            background: green;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>width</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

E o mesmo efeito você tem usando o valor `min-content`.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

        div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        p {
            width: min-content;
            background: green;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>width</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Então como vocês viram nos exemplos acima, acontece as mesmas coisas usando as três propriedades `fit-content`, `max-content` e `min-content` eu quero entender para que serve cada uma dessas três propriedades e como usá-las.

Comment: `fit-content` A largura: do comprimento interno mínimo e/ou do menor comprimento interno preferível e da largura disponível (do largura do maior filho). Não se comporta com elemento inline não, pq se vc colocar duas Divs com width:fit-content fica cada uma em uma linha. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: Valeu @hugocsl, entendi um pouco como funciona!